# ftd2xx.h on mac give me uncountable number of error. How to use it with xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, dmx512

I have some issues working with the file "ftd2xx.h" to control a DMX USB PRO by enttec.

They put a downloadable zip file in their site with a c++ example of code to control their dmx interface. I just downloaded it, create a new terminal project (C++) in XCode, pasted the project, but nothing is working! The program tell me

```
too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
```

I can't figure out why nothing is working these are the first few errors:

```
/Users/Gianmarco/Documents/EnttecTool/EnttecTool/Ftd2xx.h:60:9: error: unknown type name 'PVOID'
typedef PVOID   FT_HANDLE;
        ^
/Users/Gianmarco/Documents/EnttecTool/EnttecTool/Ftd2xx.h:61:9: error: unknown type name 'ULONG'
typedef ULONG   FT_STATUS;
        ^
/Users/Gianmarco/Documents/EnttecTool/EnttecTool/Ftd2xx.h:176:35: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
typedef void (*PFT_EVENT_HANDLER)(DWORD,DWORD);
                                  ^~~~~
/Users/Gianmarco/Documents/EnttecTool/EnttecTool/Ftd2xx.h:176:41: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
typedef void (*PFT_EVENT_HANDLER)(DWORD,DWORD);
                                        ^~~~~
/Users/Gianmarco/Documents/EnttecTool/EnttecTool/Ftd2xx.h:176:41: error: redefinition of parameter 'DWORD'
/Users/Gianmarco/Documents/EnttecTool/EnttecTool/Ftd2xx.h:176:35: note: previous declaration is here
typedef void (*PFT_EVENT_HANDLER)(DWORD,DWORD);
                                  ^
/Users/Gianmarco/Documents/EnttecTool/EnttecTool/Ftd2xx.h:192:9: error: unknown type name 'ULONG'
typedef ULONG   FT_DEVICE;
```

the ftd2xx.h file is this:

```
#ifndef FTD2XX_H
#define FTD2XX_H

#ifdef FTD2XX_EXPORTS
#define FTD2XX_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define FTD2XX_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


typedef PVOID   FT_HANDLE;
typedef ULONG   FT_STATUS;

//
// Device status
//
enum {
    FT_OK,
    FT_INVALID_HANDLE,
    FT_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND,
    FT_DEVICE_NOT_OPENED,
    FT_IO_ERROR,
    FT_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES,
    FT_INVALID_PARAMETER,
    FT_INVALID_BAUD_RATE,

    FT_DEVICE_NOT_OPENED_FOR_ERASE,
    FT_DEVICE_NOT_OPENED_FOR_WRITE,
    FT_FAILED_TO_WRITE_DEVICE,
    FT_EEPROM_READ_FAILED,
    FT_EEPROM_WRITE_FAILED,
    FT_EEPROM_ERASE_FAILED,
    FT_EEPROM_NOT_PRESENT,
    FT_EEPROM_NOT_PROGRAMMED,
    FT_INVALID_ARGS,
    FT_NOT_SUPPORTED,
    FT_OTHER_ERROR,
    FT_DEVICE_LIST_NOT_READY,
};


#define FT_SUCCESS(status) ((status) == FT_OK)

//
// FT_OpenEx Flags
//

#define FT_OPEN_BY_SERIAL_NUMBER    1
#define FT_OPEN_BY_DESCRIPTION      2
#define FT_OPEN_BY_LOCATION         4

//
// FT_ListDevices Flags (used in conjunction with FT_OpenEx Flags
//

#define FT_LIST_NUMBER_ONLY         0x80000000
#define FT_LIST_BY_INDEX            0x40000000
#define FT_LIST_ALL                 0x20000000

#define FT_LIST_MASK (FT_LIST_NUMBER_ONLY|FT_LIST_BY_INDEX|FT_LIST_ALL)

//
// Baud Rates
//

#define FT_BAUD_300         300
#define FT_BAUD_600         600
#define FT_BAUD_1200        1200
#define FT_BAUD_2400        2400
#define FT_BAUD_4800        4800
#define FT_BAUD_9600        9600
#define FT_BAUD_14400       14400
#define FT_BAUD_19200       19200
#define FT_BAUD_38400       38400
#define FT_BAUD_57600       57600
#define FT_BAUD_115200      115200
#define FT_BAUD_230400      230400
#define FT_BAUD_460800      460800
#define FT_BAUD_921600      921600

//
// Word Lengths
//

#define FT_BITS_8           (UCHAR) 8
#define FT_BITS_7           (UCHAR) 7
#define FT_BITS_6           (UCHAR) 6
#define FT_BITS_5           (UCHAR) 5

//
// Stop Bits
//

#define FT_STOP_BITS_1      (UCHAR) 0
#define FT_STOP_BITS_1_5    (UCHAR) 1
#define FT_STOP_BITS_2      (UCHAR) 2

//
// Parity
//

#define FT_PARITY_NONE      (UCHAR) 0
#define FT_PARITY_ODD       (UCHAR) 1
#define FT_PARITY_EVEN      (UCHAR) 2
#define FT_PARITY_MARK      (UCHAR) 3
#define FT_PARITY_SPACE     (UCHAR) 4

//
// Flow Control
//

#define FT_FLOW_NONE        0x0000
#define FT_FLOW_RTS_CTS     0x0100
#define FT_FLOW_DTR_DSR     0x0200
#define FT_FLOW_XON_XOFF    0x0400

//
// Purge rx and tx buffers
//
#define FT_PURGE_RX         1
#define FT_PURGE_TX         2

//
// Events
//

typedef void (*PFT_EVENT_HANDLER)(DWORD,DWORD);

#define FT_EVENT_RXCHAR         1
#define FT_EVENT_MODEM_STATUS   2

//
// Timeouts
//

#define FT_DEFAULT_RX_TIMEOUT   300
#define FT_DEFAULT_TX_TIMEOUT   300

//
// Device types
//

typedef ULONG   FT_DEVICE;

enum {
    FT_DEVICE_BM,
    FT_DEVICE_AM,
    FT_DEVICE_100AX,
    FT_DEVICE_UNKNOWN,
    FT_DEVICE_2232C,
    FT_DEVICE_232R
};


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_Open(
    int deviceNumber,
    FT_HANDLE *pHandle
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_OpenEx(
    PVOID pArg1,
    DWORD Flags,
    FT_HANDLE *pHandle
    );

FTD2XX_API 
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_ListDevices(
    PVOID pArg1,
    PVOID pArg2,
    DWORD Flags
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_Close(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_Read(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    LPVOID lpBuffer,
    DWORD nBufferSize,
    LPDWORD lpBytesReturned
    );

FTD2XX_API 
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_Write(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    LPVOID lpBuffer,
    DWORD nBufferSize,
    LPDWORD lpBytesWritten
    );

FTD2XX_API 
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_IoCtl(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    DWORD dwIoControlCode,
    LPVOID lpInBuf,
    DWORD nInBufSize,
    LPVOID lpOutBuf,
    DWORD nOutBufSize,
    LPDWORD lpBytesReturned,
    LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_SetBaudRate(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    ULONG BaudRate
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_SetDivisor(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    USHORT Divisor
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_SetDataCharacteristics(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    UCHAR WordLength,
    UCHAR StopBits,
    UCHAR Parity
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_SetFlowControl(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    USHORT FlowControl,
    UCHAR XonChar,
    UCHAR XoffChar
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_ResetDevice(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_SetDtr(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_ClrDtr(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_SetRts(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_ClrRts(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_GetModemStatus(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    ULONG *pModemStatus
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_SetChars(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    UCHAR EventChar,
    UCHAR EventCharEnabled,
    UCHAR ErrorChar,
    UCHAR ErrorCharEnabled
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_Purge(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    ULONG Mask
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_SetTimeouts(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    ULONG ReadTimeout,
    ULONG WriteTimeout
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_GetQueueStatus(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    DWORD *dwRxBytes
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_SetEventNotification(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    DWORD Mask,
    PVOID Param
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_GetStatus(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    DWORD *dwRxBytes,
    DWORD *dwTxBytes,
    DWORD *dwEventDWord
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_SetBreakOn(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_SetBreakOff(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_SetWaitMask(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    DWORD Mask
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_WaitOnMask(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    DWORD *Mask
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_GetEventStatus(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    DWORD *dwEventDWord
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_ReadEE(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    DWORD dwWordOffset,
    LPWORD lpwValue
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_WriteEE(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    DWORD dwWordOffset,
    WORD wValue
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_EraseEE(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle
    );

//
// structure to hold program data for FT_Program function
//
typedef struct ft_program_data {

    DWORD Signature1;           // Header - must be 0x00000000 
    DWORD Signature2;           // Header - must be 0xffffffff
    DWORD Version;              // Header - FT_PROGRAM_DATA version
                                //          0 = original
                                //          1 = FT2232C extensions
                                //          2 = FT232R extensions

    WORD VendorId;              // 0x0403
    WORD ProductId;             // 0x6001
    char *Manufacturer;         // "FTDI"
    char *ManufacturerId;       // "FT"
    char *Description;          // "USB HS Serial Converter"
    char *SerialNumber;         // "FT000001" if fixed, or NULL
    WORD MaxPower;              // 0 < MaxPower <= 500
    WORD PnP;                   // 0 = disabled, 1 = enabled
    WORD SelfPowered;           // 0 = bus powered, 1 = self powered
    WORD RemoteWakeup;          // 0 = not capable, 1 = capable
    //
    // Rev4 extensions
    //
    UCHAR Rev4;                 // non-zero if Rev4 chip, zero otherwise
    UCHAR IsoIn;                // non-zero if in endpoint is isochronous
    UCHAR IsoOut;               // non-zero if out endpoint is isochronous
    UCHAR PullDownEnable;       // non-zero if pull down enabled
    UCHAR SerNumEnable;         // non-zero if serial number to be used
    UCHAR USBVersionEnable;     // non-zero if chip uses USBVersion
    WORD USBVersion;            // BCD (0x0200 => USB2)
    //
    // FT2232C extensions
    //
    UCHAR Rev5;                 // non-zero if Rev5 chip, zero otherwise
    UCHAR IsoInA;               // non-zero if in endpoint is isochronous
    UCHAR IsoInB;               // non-zero if in endpoint is isochronous
    UCHAR IsoOutA;              // non-zero if out endpoint is isochronous
    UCHAR IsoOutB;              // non-zero if out endpoint is isochronous
    UCHAR PullDownEnable5;      // non-zero if pull down enabled
    UCHAR SerNumEnable5;        // non-zero if serial number to be used
    UCHAR USBVersionEnable5;    // non-zero if chip uses USBVersion
    WORD USBVersion5;           // BCD (0x0200 => USB2)
    UCHAR AIsHighCurrent;       // non-zero if interface is high current
    UCHAR BIsHighCurrent;       // non-zero if interface is high current
    UCHAR IFAIsFifo;            // non-zero if interface is 245 FIFO
    UCHAR IFAIsFifoTar;         // non-zero if interface is 245 FIFO CPU target
    UCHAR IFAIsFastSer;         // non-zero if interface is Fast serial
    UCHAR AIsVCP;               // non-zero if interface is to use VCP drivers
    UCHAR IFBIsFifo;            // non-zero if interface is 245 FIFO
    UCHAR IFBIsFifoTar;         // non-zero if interface is 245 FIFO CPU target
    UCHAR IFBIsFastSer;         // non-zero if interface is Fast serial
    UCHAR BIsVCP;               // non-zero if interface is to use VCP drivers
    //
    // FT232R extensions
    //
    UCHAR UseExtOsc;            // Use External Oscillator
    UCHAR HighDriveIOs;         // High Drive I/Os
    UCHAR EndpointSize;         // Endpoint size

    UCHAR PullDownEnableR;      // non-zero if pull down enabled
    UCHAR SerNumEnableR;        // non-zero if serial number to be used

    UCHAR InvertTXD;            // non-zero if invert TXD
    UCHAR InvertRXD;            // non-zero if invert RXD
    UCHAR InvertRTS;            // non-zero if invert RTS
    UCHAR InvertCTS;            // non-zero if invert CTS
    UCHAR InvertDTR;            // non-zero if invert DTR
    UCHAR InvertDSR;            // non-zero if invert DSR
    UCHAR InvertDCD;            // non-zero if invert DCD
    UCHAR InvertRI;             // non-zero if invert RI

    UCHAR Cbus0;                // Cbus Mux control
    UCHAR Cbus1;                // Cbus Mux control
    UCHAR Cbus2;                // Cbus Mux control
    UCHAR Cbus3;                // Cbus Mux control
    UCHAR Cbus4;                // Cbus Mux control

    UCHAR RIsD2XX;              // non-zero if using D2XX driver

} FT_PROGRAM_DATA, *PFT_PROGRAM_DATA;

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_EE_Program(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    PFT_PROGRAM_DATA pData
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_EE_ProgramEx(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    PFT_PROGRAM_DATA pData,
    char *Manufacturer,
    char *ManufacturerId,
    char *Description,
    char *SerialNumber
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_EE_Read(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    PFT_PROGRAM_DATA pData
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_EE_ReadEx(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    PFT_PROGRAM_DATA pData,
    char *Manufacturer,
    char *ManufacturerId,
    char *Description,
    char *SerialNumber
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_EE_UASize(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    LPDWORD lpdwSize
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_EE_UAWrite(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    PUCHAR pucData,
    DWORD dwDataLen
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_EE_UARead(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    PUCHAR pucData,
    DWORD dwDataLen,
    LPDWORD lpdwBytesRead
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_SetLatencyTimer(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    UCHAR ucLatency
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_GetLatencyTimer(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    PUCHAR pucLatency
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_SetBitMode(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    UCHAR ucMask,
    UCHAR ucEnable
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_GetBitMode(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    PUCHAR pucMode
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_SetUSBParameters(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    ULONG ulInTransferSize,
    ULONG ulOutTransferSize
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_SetDeadmanTimeout(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    ULONG ulDeadmanTimeout
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_GetDeviceInfo(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    FT_DEVICE *lpftDevice,
    LPDWORD lpdwID,
    PCHAR SerialNumber,
    PCHAR Description,
    LPVOID Dummy
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_StopInTask(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_RestartInTask(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_SetResetPipeRetryCount(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    DWORD dwCount
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_ResetPort(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_CyclePort(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle
    );


//
// Win32-type functions
//

FTD2XX_API
FT_HANDLE WINAPI FT_W32_CreateFile(
    LPCTSTR                 lpszName,
    DWORD                   dwAccess,
    DWORD                   dwShareMode,
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES   lpSecurityAttributes,
    DWORD                   dwCreate,
    DWORD                   dwAttrsAndFlags,
    HANDLE                  hTemplate
    );

FTD2XX_API
BOOL WINAPI FT_W32_CloseHandle(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle
    );

FTD2XX_API
BOOL WINAPI FT_W32_ReadFile(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    LPVOID lpBuffer,
    DWORD nBufferSize,
    LPDWORD lpBytesReturned,
    LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
    );

FTD2XX_API
BOOL WINAPI FT_W32_WriteFile(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    LPVOID lpBuffer,
    DWORD nBufferSize,
    LPDWORD lpBytesWritten,
    LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
    );

FTD2XX_API
DWORD WINAPI FT_W32_GetLastError(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle
    );

FTD2XX_API
BOOL WINAPI FT_W32_GetOverlappedResult(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped,
    LPDWORD lpdwBytesTransferred,
    BOOL bWait
    );

FTD2XX_API
BOOL WINAPI FT_W32_CancelIo(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle
    );


//
// Win32 COMM API type functions
//
typedef struct _FTCOMSTAT {
    DWORD fCtsHold : 1;
    DWORD fDsrHold : 1;
    DWORD fRlsdHold : 1;
    DWORD fXoffHold : 1;
    DWORD fXoffSent : 1;
    DWORD fEof : 1;
    DWORD fTxim : 1;
    DWORD fReserved : 25;
    DWORD cbInQue;
    DWORD cbOutQue;
} FTCOMSTAT, *LPFTCOMSTAT;

typedef struct _FTDCB {
    DWORD DCBlength;      /* sizeof(FTDCB)                   */
    DWORD BaudRate;       /* Baudrate at which running       */
    DWORD fBinary: 1;     /* Binary Mode (skip EOF check)    */
    DWORD fParity: 1;     /* Enable parity checking          */
    DWORD fOutxCtsFlow:1; /* CTS handshaking on output       */
    DWORD fOutxDsrFlow:1; /* DSR handshaking on output       */
    DWORD fDtrControl:2;  /* DTR Flow control                */
    DWORD fDsrSensitivity:1; /* DSR Sensitivity              */
    DWORD fTXContinueOnXoff: 1; /* Continue TX when Xoff sent */
    DWORD fOutX: 1;       /* Enable output X-ON/X-OFF        */
    DWORD fInX: 1;        /* Enable input X-ON/X-OFF         */
    DWORD fErrorChar: 1;  /* Enable Err Replacement          */
    DWORD fNull: 1;       /* Enable Null stripping           */
    DWORD fRtsControl:2;  /* Rts Flow control                */
    DWORD fAbortOnError:1; /* Abort all reads and writes on Error */
    DWORD fDummy2:17;     /* Reserved                        */
    WORD wReserved;       /* Not currently used              */
    WORD XonLim;          /* Transmit X-ON threshold         */
    WORD XoffLim;         /* Transmit X-OFF threshold        */
    BYTE ByteSize;        /* Number of bits/byte, 4-8        */
    BYTE Parity;          /* 0-4=None,Odd,Even,Mark,Space    */
    BYTE StopBits;        /* 0,1,2 = 1, 1.5, 2               */
    char XonChar;         /* Tx and Rx X-ON character        */
    char XoffChar;        /* Tx and Rx X-OFF character       */
    char ErrorChar;       /* Error replacement char          */
    char EofChar;         /* End of Input character          */
    char EvtChar;         /* Received Event character        */
    WORD wReserved1;      /* Fill for now.                   */
} FTDCB, *LPFTDCB;

typedef struct _FTTIMEOUTS {
    DWORD ReadIntervalTimeout;          /* Maximum time between read chars. */
    DWORD ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier;   /* Multiplier of characters.        */
    DWORD ReadTotalTimeoutConstant;     /* Constant in milliseconds.        */
    DWORD WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier;  /* Multiplier of characters.        */
    DWORD WriteTotalTimeoutConstant;    /* Constant in milliseconds.        */
} FTTIMEOUTS,*LPFTTIMEOUTS;


FTD2XX_API
BOOL WINAPI FT_W32_ClearCommBreak(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle
    );

FTD2XX_API
BOOL WINAPI FT_W32_ClearCommError(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    LPDWORD lpdwErrors,
    LPFTCOMSTAT lpftComstat
    );

FTD2XX_API
BOOL WINAPI FT_W32_EscapeCommFunction(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    DWORD dwFunc
    );

FTD2XX_API
BOOL WINAPI FT_W32_GetCommModemStatus(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    LPDWORD lpdwModemStatus
    );

FTD2XX_API
BOOL WINAPI FT_W32_GetCommState(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    LPFTDCB lpftDcb
    );

FTD2XX_API
BOOL WINAPI FT_W32_GetCommTimeouts(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    FTTIMEOUTS *pTimeouts
    );

FTD2XX_API
BOOL WINAPI FT_W32_PurgeComm(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    DWORD dwMask
    );

FTD2XX_API
BOOL WINAPI FT_W32_SetCommBreak(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle
    );

FTD2XX_API
BOOL WINAPI FT_W32_SetCommMask(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    ULONG ulEventMask
    );

FTD2XX_API
BOOL WINAPI FT_W32_GetCommMask(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    LPDWORD lpdwEventMask
    );

FTD2XX_API
BOOL WINAPI FT_W32_SetCommState(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    LPFTDCB lpftDcb
    );

FTD2XX_API
BOOL WINAPI FT_W32_SetCommTimeouts(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    FTTIMEOUTS *pTimeouts
    );

FTD2XX_API
BOOL WINAPI FT_W32_SetupComm(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    DWORD dwReadBufferSize,
    DWORD dwWriteBufferSize
    );

FTD2XX_API
BOOL WINAPI FT_W32_WaitCommEvent(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    PULONG pulEvent,
    LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
    );


//
// Device information
//

typedef struct _ft_device_list_info_node {
    ULONG Flags;
    ULONG Type;
    ULONG ID;
    DWORD LocId;
    char SerialNumber[16];
    char Description[64];
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle;
} FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE;


FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_CreateDeviceInfoList(
    LPDWORD lpdwNumDevs
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_GetDeviceInfoList(
    FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE *pDest,
    LPDWORD lpdwNumDevs
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_GetDeviceInfoDetail(
    DWORD dwIndex,
    LPDWORD lpdwFlags,
    LPDWORD lpdwType,
    LPDWORD lpdwID,
    LPDWORD lpdwLocId,
    LPVOID lpSerialNumber,
    LPVOID lpDescription,
    FT_HANDLE *pftHandle
    );


//
// Version information
//

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_GetDriverVersion(
    FT_HANDLE ftHandle,
    LPDWORD lpdwVersion
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_GetLibraryVersion(
    LPDWORD lpdwVersion
    );


FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_Rescan(
    void
    );

FTD2XX_API
FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_Reload(
    WORD wVid,
    WORD wPid
    );


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif


#endif  /* FTD2XX_H */
```

Can you help me to figure out what is the problem with my mac that can't run the program? I have never programmed in C++ on Mac or used used Xcode.

Comment: `PVOID` and `ULONG` look like Windows API types.  Are you sure the header/library you're using are going to work on a Mac?  It's easy to fix up the types in the header to make things compile, but unless you have a Mac OS X-compatible library to link with, you're going to be out of luck.

Comment: I just went over to that site and downloaded the package in question.  It's not going to work on your mac - it requires you to link against their Windows DLL to work, and that DLL most certainly won't work on your Mac.

Comment: nope, i think all the stuff they create is for windows only, is my fault thinking as in java there are no differences? is there any method to use this file easily in OSX?

Comment: No, there is no way to use that file in Mac OS X.  You can get a VM and work with it there if you want, I guess.  If you can convince the vendor to open up their interface a bit, you could probably write your own library to talk to it without too much trouble.

Comment: thank you carl norum. If i can steal few more of your time, is there a method to use that Enttec interface under OSX environment?

Comment: I have no idea - that's a question to ask Enttec.

Comment: what kind of opening are you talking about, there are many specification for the interface..

Comment: It's a USB device, right?  That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: There is a link at that page to a Mac OS X control app.  I don't know if you could hack into that someplace, maybe that's a way to go?

Comment: you mean to crack the PRO-manager program to understand how to use the interface in OSX? I think it's a bit too difficult for my skills...

Answer (score 2):

I've recently used it ftd2xx.h on osx. In the D2XX dmg  provided by FTDI there is also a **WinTypes.h** which you need to add to your Xcode project and of course link against the provided .dylib.

In your case, WinTypes.h seems to be the key because it contains the missing typedefs Xcode complains about.It sounds counter intuitive to use WinTypes.h on an OSX project, but it does the job(even on Android)